# Is porting an AAA iPhone 3D game for the Nintendo DSi possible?

Tags: iphone, porting, nintendo-ds

As my complex question says, methinks, quite much search would be involved, if I wanted to solve it alone.

I don't know anything about these 2 platforms and getting acquainted with both their Hardware and Programming abilities / tools would be quite time-consuming.

So, would kindly ask the community:

(Thinking at a huge company level and not as an Indie)
**what would be the greatest issues during porting the 3D AAA game on the programming side?**

(Mentioning the most significant ones would be sufficient)

Many many thanx,
good - Byte.

Answer (score 2):

The DSi has little RAM (~16Mo) to work with, fairly slow processors (66MHz) and limited number of polygons. So direct conversion of a modern 3D game will be a nightmare. You're much better to consider adapting your assets to the DSi specs rather than trying to stick "as close as possible" to the iPhone version.